# Why set VISIBLE=NOW in /etc/profile?

Tags: bash, ssh, docker

I'm reading a [Dockerfile - Dockerizing an SSH Service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/) and it contains the following code:

```
 ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
 RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile
```

Just curious what the purpose of that is?

TIA,
Ole

P.S Great article here on ways to avoid running an SSH Server in a Docker container: https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/

Comment: Have you tried searching for `VISIBLE` in the init scripts of the container? And specifically in the pam setup and per-user shell setup?

Comment: Those variables are just for explaining the scope of env-vars; see the "environment variables'" section on the same page https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/#environment-variables

Comment: That's hilarious. @thaJeztah is basically stating that the point of those two lines is to convey that your `ENV` vars will not be available in the container when ssh'ing in, so you need to copy them to `/etc/profile` and you can do that using the format indicated. There is no `VISIBLE` env var that affects the environment.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's an example of how to pass environment variables when running a Dockerized SSHD service.  SSHD scrubs the environment, therefore `ENV` variables contained in `Dockerfile` must be pushed to `/etc/profile` in order for them to be available.

Comment: What do you mean by *SSHD scrubs the environment*? could you elaborate please?

Comment: Resets the Docker environment so that if you have variables initialized in it, SSHD will delete those.  It's been a while but I think that's what I meant.  It may be explained further in the article I referenced.